# Multiple disks power problem

Tags: usb, power

I have four 500Gb disks I want to connect to a Pi for RAID setup. They are rated at 1A each, which should be the max current they will draw. I've connected them to [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-ports-USB-3-0-Hub-portable-mini-support-sd-card-with-a-5V-4A-20W-powered/253078580312?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) USB hub. The drives keep failing. If I plug in all four, one of them fails after a few minutes. When I try three, one of them failed after a day.

The drives fail temporarily. If I reconnect them and poweroff/on, they are operable again. When I say fail, I mean they start cluncing, and become unavailable.

I'm suspecting this is a current supply issue, and that the current is drawn from the Pi USB port and not the USB power source, or some combination of the two.

Could a solution be to cut the power wire (red) coming from the Pi USB cable to force use of the external power source?

Comment: The HDDs are connected to the hub, not the Pi? The Pi is connected to the hub? I do not see how modifying the cable between the Pi and the hub solves this issue. I will even go so far and say that this is not the Pi's fault but the hub's. Maybe its promised 4A are not that reliable after all.

Comment: Yes I agree this is the most likely problem.